# Deploy with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

First Laravel Project.

I want to deploy my Laravel project to a Hoster. I have FTP access to it, but I don't want to tinker with filezilla everytime I change something. Plus my Development and 'Finished' projects has some differences (for example Debugbar and different DataBase authentication. What's the best method to deploy a Laravel Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in many ways. So I am going to give a headstart.

> **Warning**: This might not be everything you need to know. I recommend you to learn more about, deployment,ssh, version controlling, apache vhosts, etc , **this is just a headstart**

Here is how I do it on my Ubuntu server with apache, php and mysql.

I use Git for version controlling and bitbucket and github for managing repositories.

1 - make my project a git repository.

2 - push the repo to bitbucket.

3 - connect to the remote server through ssh and setup the apache vhosts, databases etc.

- create a vhost `/etc/apache/sites-available/somesite.com.conf` file
- add the entry to `/etc/hosts` file

4 - pull the repo from bitbucket to remote server, create and bring the required changes to the production .env file

5 - do a `composer install`

6 - run `php artisan key:generate` and `php artisan migrate`

7 - turn on the site

- run `sudo a2ensite somesite.com.conf`
- run `sudo service apache2 reload`

now the site its up and ready to go.